# How to align two ellipsoids along center and long axes?

Tags: computational-geometry, code-request, geometric-transform

I'm struggling to understand [rotation/translation transforms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricTransforms.html) as applied to things like spheres and ellipsoids. Take the following silly example.

Given this pair of random ellipsoids, how do I find a rotation/translation that aligns their centers and their long axes? (no matter that they differ in sizes, only care about their centers and long axes being aligned). Are the two possible geometric transformations equivalent? (Say, moving ellipsoid 1 to be aligned to the fixed ellipsoid 2, and vice versa?)

```
SeedRandom[1234];
twoRandomEllipsoids = 
  Table[{Ellipsoid[RandomReal[10, {3}], RandomReal[{1, 2}, 3]]}, {2}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], twoRandomEllipsoids}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first create 2 ellipsoids with random center and random orientation.

```
center = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}} = 
   RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {2, 3}];
axlen = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {3, 2}] // Transpose
tr1 = AffineTransform[{rm1 = 
     RotationMatrix[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}]], center[[1]]}];
tr2 = AffineTransform[{rm2 = 
     RotationMatrix[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}]], center[[2]]}];


ax1 = (IdentityMatrix[3] axlen[[1]]) . Transpose@rm1;
ax2 = (IdentityMatrix[3] axlen[[2]]) . Transpose@rm2 ;


e1 = tr1[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, axlen[[1]]]];
e2 = tr2[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, axlen[[2]]]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], e1, e2, 
  Line[{e1[[1]], e1[[1]] + #} & /@ ax1], 
  Line[{e2[[1]], e2[[1]] + #} & /@ ax2]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Where `center` is a list of the 2 centers and `ax1` and `ax2` are lists of the half axes of the 2 ellipsoids.

If we normalize the axes, we get orthogonal rotation matrices that transforms the coordinate aligned axes to the actual orientations.

```
rot1 = Normalize /@ ax1;
rot2 = Normalize /@ ax2;
```

E.g. the coordinate aligned axes `(axlen[[1]] IdentityMatrix[3])` would be rotated into `ax1` by:

```
(axlen[[1]] IdentityMatrix[3]) . rot1 == ax1
(*True*)
```

Note that we multiply by the rotation matrix `rot1` from the right, because we are working with row vectors.

On the other hand, the inverse of `rot1`, what is the same as the transposed, will transform `ax1` back to the coordinated aligned  half axes.

Therefore, to rotate half axes `ax2` to the orientation of `ax1` we can first rotate back to coordinates alignment by `Transpose[r2]` and in a second rotation to alignment with ax1 by: `r1`:

```
rot12=  Transpose[rot2] . rot1;
ax3= ax2 . rot12
```

With this we can now define the affine translation that maps ellipsoid e2 on the center and direction of ellipsoid e1:

```
tr3 = AffineTransform[{rot12, 
    center[[1]] - center[[2]] . Transpose[rot12]}];
```

Note that the center of `e2` is rotated by `r12` and we need to undo this rotation by `Transpose[r12]`.

Now we can apply the transformation and draw the result:

```
e3 = tr3[e2];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], e1, e3, 
  Line[{e1[[1]], e1[[1]] + #} & /@ ax1], 
  Line[{e3[[1]], e3[[1]] + #} & /@ ax3]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks! This looks very cool. In the last image, however, aren't the major axes perpendicular to each other? I was meaning 'aligned' as both major axes would have the same 'direction', if that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Of course you are right. The major axes should be aligned. I had an error in the code and fixed it. Hope I got it right this time.

Comment: Hmmm. I see the major axes perpendicular (crossing each other at the center, in a right angle). Maybe my idea of 'aligned' is not clear? If the angle between the major angles disappeared in your final image, that'd be my idea of 'aligned'. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: As you can see from the code, the axes of both ellipses are drawn and they coincide. Therefore you can see only one pair of axes. I think this means "alignment".

Comment: You're right, that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll just show the translation.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
theparameters = Table[{RandomReal[10, {3}], RandomReal[{1, 2}, 3]}, {2}];

shifted = 
 GeometricTransformation[twoRandomEllipsoids[[1]], 
  TranslationTransform[-theparameters[[1, 1]] + theparameters[[2, 1]]]];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Red, shifted, Green, twoRandomEllipsoids[[2]]}]
```

[image]

The major axis is trivial since by your construction the major axis of each ellipsoid is aligned to a coordinate axis.  Just find which terms are largest in each of your ellipsoids.  If one is along x and the other along z, then simply rotate one by $\pi/2$ about the third axis ($y$) so as to align its $z$ axis with the other's $x$ axis.